# Big cache_form slows Drupal website and the whole server

Tags: 7, forms, database

I have a custom form in my site. After couple of months a big issue appears.

Not only that the table cache_form has become huge, but also if I empty that table and disable my custom form, the cache_form keeps increasing over and over, so my website and whole server becomes very slow.

Some spambots are killing my server and I've already tried "Bad behavior" module, but there aren't any positive results.
Also my custom form has a Honeypot protection, so I receive very few spams from there, but the bots keep slowing everything.

Can anyone post some advice, anything will be useful?

Comment: Nearly sure we have a dup for this.

Comment: Can you post the duplicate post?

Comment: The form cache table should be cleared periodically by [`system_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_cron/7). Is your site set up properly to run cron tasks regularly?